# how may database queries could you have on a single page?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how many database connections could you run on a single file? I am trying to redo a webpage that list different search criteria depending on the product category. For example if the user selects refrigerators he would be able to filter the search by brands, type, color, capacity etc... For all these different filters to be listed I make a new query to the database. I have listed a piece of my code below. Is this the proper way to handle this or is there a better way of doing it? Should you use different variables for each query or is it okay to use the same variables?

I was also wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on how to filter my main query when the user selects multiple check boxes.

Comment: I’d suggest looking at AJAX, and caching.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit. It depends on database setup, architecture and tuning is responsible for the performance.
And number of queries should be caused by database architecture only. Use as many queries as many you need. Do not reduce number of queries at any cost, only in pursue of performance.

Comment: Companjo thank you for taking the time out to answer my question. I was wondering if you can show me or point me in the right direction on how to filter my main query when the user selects multiple check boxes. I been search on the net for answer but haven't found anything useful.